# Moving Workflows and Lists?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, list

I have a list and workflow that I created under HR (employees are not supposed to be able to view this list).  At the present moment I can allow the employee to view the workflow (that I linked to another site (a form they are to complete and submit)), ONLY if the employee is able to view the HR site they are not supposed to view. If the employee does not have permissions to view the (Illegal) site, then they can't even view the form to submit it and update HR's list.

I noticed when I did give employees permission to the link on one HR site (for all employees) and permission to the private HR site (so they can view the form), after they select submit or cancel, the employee is taken to the private HR home page they are not supposed to view.

How can I keep the list for HR private to ONLY HR and allow the employees to view the form and submit it without it allowing the employees to view the private HR site? The only thing the employees should be able to view would be their own address, that should pre-populate the form when the form is opened for the employee who is logged in to the computer (I dont know where to begin for this either). Then my other thought is, if they are updating their address why not have the form blank the only other thing they will add is their name, unless that should be pre-populated as well.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that on the public site, you'd have a list that the employee can fill out to initiate the workflow.  Then using impersenation steps, create an item in the private site so that workflow processes can continue without having to give the user access.  Once the workflow is complete on the private site, you could update information in the public site to reflect the outcome.

Comment: @PirateEric-Ok, so I have a form that was created in a workflow, but in order for that employee to fill out that form, they are given access to the site they are not supposed to view...(when the link on the site that is ok for them to view, a form opens. the only way they will view the site they are not supposed to is when they select submit or cancel). So if I set up an impersonation then they should be able to view the form, but not the HR site when they select submit or cancel? How can I get this to take them back to the previous page? Or Can't I. otherwise they will receive an error msg.

Comment: Well you could always use a Source query string parameter on the link so that when the user does a cancel or save, they're redirected to where you want them to go.

Comment: @PirateEric-please forgive me for being so new, but I don't know how to do that yet. How do I do this?

Comment: If you provide a link to the form like http://sp.domain.com/site/sitecollection/lists/listname/myform.aspx, you can add ?Source=http://yahoo.com to that hyperlink and when completed or canceled, the user will be returned to what you specify as the source address.

Comment: @PirateEric _ I added "sp.tkseportal.com/hr/Pages/costcenters/hr/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?TemplateID={f922efb0-8b46-40aa-9007-8eb73b70a308}" and when I select the link I get "File Not Found"

Comment: I re-added the previous link and now when the user selects cancel or submit, the data is submitted but the user ends up at the human resources workflow site page. I don't know, this isn't seeming consistent to me. One would think if I were to do what I had done previously, I would have the same end result...lol. Just trying to learn and figure this process out.

Comment: @PirateEric- I DID IT!!!! oh this seems like a great accomplishment! There are other things I need to do with this, but at least this part is completed! Thank you for your help! I restructured the Source to = the page I wanted the user to end up! Thank you!!!

Comment: Great, glad you got it working!